# Error while parsing Gif in Typescript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, animated-gif

I am trying to parse a .GIF in Typescript. What I really want is to extract the frames, but that if a bit much right now.
I am right now trying to adapt the script from:
http://slbkbs.org/jsgif/ to work in typescript.
Here is my attempt: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-syn3av
I feel like I am VERY close, but I am getting an error on line 296 as I parse a block. I am at position 205 in the .GIF file.
If anyone has attempted parsing .GIFs before, I would really appreciate info on how to handle unexpected data.

On line 335 of gif.ts

```
switch (String.fromCharCode(block.sentinel)) {
  case '!':
    block.type = 'ext';
    parseExt(block);
    break;
  case ',':
    block.type = 'img';
    parseImg(block);
    break;
  case ';':
    block.type = 'eof';
    handler.eof && handler.eof(block);
    break;
  default:
    throw new Error('Unknown block: 0x' + block.sentinel.toString(16)); // TODO: Pad this with a 0.
}
```

the result of String.fromCharCode(block.sentinel) seems to be: 0xfd or ý and that is no good.... Am I out of order with how I increment my position?

Update:
I changed the .GIF, and now I am getting an error code: 0x0

Thanks!

Comment: You are testing UTF-8 encoded characters instead of bytes, that's not going to go well. Use [`TypedArray`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray).

Comment: @amn If you post that as an answer I will accept it.